# libgdx Clicklistener doesnt work, What is missing?

Tags: java, libgdx

Im new with libgdx. Im going to code a android game. The Player is moving by itself, but if you touch the screen(or click with the mouse) the player will stop. I want to add a pause button. It do render, but if I touch/click on the button the listener doesnt react, just the player stops.

Thats the class with the imporant methods about the button:

```
public class PlayState extends State {

private EntityManager entityManager;
private Player player;
private Texture background;
private Texture filter;
private BitmapFont font;
private Sound click, boost;
private Drug drug;
private Border border;
private House house;

public static final int FIELD_SIZE_HEIGHT = 1000;
public static final int FIELD_SIZE_WIDTH = 500;

private int collectedDrugs;
private boolean pause, renderLost;
private boolean boostSound;

private ImageButton button;
private Drawable drawable;
private Texture textureBtn;

public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    entityManager = new EntityManager();
    player = new Player(this, 100, 100);
    border = new Border();
    background = new Texture("bggame.png");
    filter = new Texture("filter.png");
    cam.setToOrtho(false, MinniMafia.WIDTH, MinniMafia.HEIGHT);
    click = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("Click.mp3"));
    boost = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("boost.mp3"));
    drug = new Drug();
    house = new House();
    collectedDrugs = 0;
    font = new BitmapFont();
    entityManager.addEntity(player);
    entityManager.addEntity(drug);
    entityManager.addEntity(border);
    entityManager.addEntity(house);

    pause = false;
    renderLost = false;
    boostSound = false;

    Stage stage;
    textureBtn = new Texture("pausebtn.png");
    drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(textureBtn));
    button = new ImageButton(drawable);
    button.setPosition(cam.position.x + cam.viewportWidth/2 - 50, cam.position.y + cam.viewportHeight/2 - 50);
    button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void     clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)  {
            System.out.println("Button Pressed");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void handleInput() {
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        click.play(0.2f);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        player.setStop(true);
        boostSound = false;
    } else {
        if (!boostSound) {
            boost.play(0.2f);
            boostSound = true;
        }
        player.setStop(false);

    }

}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    if (!pause) {
        handleInput();
        entityManager.updateEntities(dt);
        setCam();
        button.setPosition(cam.position.x + cam.viewportWidth/2 - 60, cam.position.y + cam.viewportHeight/2 - 60);
        if (drug.collides(player.getBounds())) {
            entityManager.disposeEntity(drug);
            player.setGotDrug(true);
        }
        if (border.collides(player.getBounds()) && !border.isOpen()) {
            pause = true;
            renderLost = true;

        }
        if (house.collides(player.getBounds()) && player.isGotDrug()) {
            player.setGotDrug(false);
            collectedDrugs++;
            drug = new Drug();
            entityManager.addEntity(drug);
        }
    } else if (renderLost = true) {
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            gsm.set(new MenuState(gsm));
            dispose();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(background, 0, 0);
    entityManager.renderEntities(sb);
    button.draw(sb, 10f);
    font.draw(sb, "" + collectedDrugs, cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2 + 10, cam.position.y - cam.viewportHeight / 2 + 20);
    if (renderLost) {
        sb.draw(filter, cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2, cam.position.y - cam.viewportHeight / 2);
        font.draw(sb, "LOST! SCORE:" + collectedDrugs, cam.position.x - 50, cam.position.y);
    }
    sb.end();
}
```

I suppose that there is missing sth, but I can not figure it out. Can sb help me please?

LG bttl

Comment: The UI elements in LibGDX don't work unless managed by a Stage object. Google ""LibGDX Scene2D" for documentation. Also one thing that I don't think is clear in the documentation is that you should use ChangeListener instead of ClickListener with UI objects to get traditional behavior.

Comment: Ty it works with a stage

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your Stage as InputProcessor for Scene2d to work. [Documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d)

For using Stage and your own code as InputProcessor, add both to an InputMultiplexer and use this.